# Swagger can't start in jhipster when using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, swagger, jhipster

I'm working on application with jhipster. It was good so far however today I have an issue that I can't resolve.

When I use Eclipse I can't start application. I suppose that it is caused of Swagger can't start.

It looks like that:

```
    The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\twloszki\.m2\repository\org\liquibase\liquibase-core\3.5.5\liquibase-core-3.5.5.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/Users/twloszki/.m2/repository/org/liquibase/liquibase-core/3.5.5/lib/snakeyaml-1.13.jar
13:22:12.567 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Included patterns for restart : []
13:22:12.567 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Excluded patterns for restart : [/spring-boot-starter/target/classes/, /spring-boot-autoconfigure/target/classes/, /spring-boot-starter-[\w-]+/, /spring-boot/target/classes/, /spring-boot-actuator/target/classes/, /spring-boot-devtools/target/classes/]
13:22:12.567 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls - Matching URLs for reloading : [file:/C:/GSMR/ICOMS-web/target/classes/]

        ██╗ ██╗   ██╗ ████████╗ ███████╗   ██████╗ ████████╗ ████████╗ ███████╗
        ██║ ██║   ██║ ╚══██╔══╝ ██╔═══██╗ ██╔════╝ ╚══██╔══╝ ██╔═════╝ ██╔═══██╗
        ██║ ████████║    ██║    ███████╔╝ ╚█████╗     ██║    ██████╗   ███████╔╝
  ██╗   ██║ ██╔═══██║    ██║    ██╔════╝   ╚═══██╗    ██║    ██╔═══╝   ██╔══██║
  ╚██████╔╝ ██║   ██║ ████████╗ ██║       ██████╔╝    ██║    ████████╗ ██║  ╚██╗
   ╚═════╝  ╚═╝   ╚═╝ ╚═══════╝ ╚═╝       ╚═════╝     ╚═╝    ╚═══════╝ ╚═╝   ╚═╝

:: JHipster   :: Running Spring Boot 1.5.14.RELEASE ::
:: http://www.jhipster.tech ::

2019-01-21 13:22:13.580  INFO 2492 --- [  restartedMain] com.App        : Starting App on PC
2019-01-21 13:22:13.580 DEBUG 2492 --- [  restartedMain] com.App        : Running with Spring Boot v1.5.14.RELEASE, Spring v4.3.18.RELEASE
2019-01-21 13:22:13.580  INFO 2492 --- [  restartedMain] com.App        : The following profiles are active: swagger,dev
2019-01-21 13:22:13.861 DEBUG 2492 --- [kground-preinit] org.jboss.logging                        : Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Slf4jLoggerProvider found via system property
2019-01-21 13:22:16.660 DEBUG 2492 --- [  restartedMain] p.w.g.config.AsyncConfiguration          : Creating Async Task Executor
2019-01-21 13:22:17.347 DEBUG 2492 --- [  restartedMain] p.w.g.config.MetricsConfiguration        : Registering JVM gauges
2019-01-21 13:22:17.472 DEBUG 2492 --- [  restartedMain] p.w.g.config.MetricsConfiguration        : Monitoring the datasource
2019-01-21 13:22:17.472 DEBUG 2492 --- [  restartedMain] p.w.g.config.MetricsConfiguration        : Initializing Metrics JMX reporting
2019-01-21 13:22:18.421 DEBUG 2492 --- [  restartedMain] com.config.WebConfigurer  : Registering CORS filter
2019-01-21 13:22:18.625  INFO 2492 --- [  restartedMain] com.config.WebConfigurer  : Web application configuration, using profiles: swagger
2019-01-21 13:22:18.625 DEBUG 2492 --- [  restartedMain] com.config.WebConfigurer  : Initializing Metrics registries
2019-01-21 13:22:18.625 DEBUG 2492 --- [  restartedMain] com.config.WebConfigurer  : Registering Metrics Filter
2019-01-21 13:22:18.625 DEBUG 2492 --- [  restartedMain] com.config.WebConfigurer  : Registering Metrics Servlet
2019-01-21 13:22:18.625  INFO 2492 --- [  restartedMain] com.config.WebConfigurer  : Web application fully configured
2019-01-21 13:22:18.922 DEBUG 2492 --- [  restartedMain] p.w.g.config.DatabaseConfiguration       : Configuring Liquibase
2019-01-21 13:22:18.937  WARN 2492 --- [port-Executor-1] i.g.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Starting Liquibase asynchronously, your database might not be ready at startup!
2019-01-21 13:22:23.527 DEBUG 2492 --- [  restartedMain] c.ehcache.core.Ehcache-usersByLogin      : Initialize successful.
2019-01-21 13:22:23.527 DEBUG 2492 --- [  restartedMain] c.ehcache.core.Ehcache-usersByEmail      : Initialize successful.
2019-01-21 13:22:23.543 DEBUG 2492 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.w.g.domain.DictionaryValue       : Initialize successful.
2019-01-21 13:22:23.543 DEBUG 2492 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.w.g.domain.DictionaryType        : Initialize successful.
2019-01-21 13:22:23.543 DEBUG 2492 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.domain.Line     : Initialize successful.
2019-01-21 13:22:23.543 DEBUG 2492 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.domain.Section  : Initialize successful.
2019-01-21 13:22:23.583 DEBUG 2492 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.domain.WorkCost     : Initialize successful.
2019-01-21 13:22:23.585 DEBUG 2492 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.domain.WorkAttachment        : Initialize successful.
```

The next step should be:

```
2019-01-21 13:07:24.089 DEBUG 10764 --- [  restartedMain] i.g.j.c.apidoc.SwaggerConfiguration      : Starting Swagger
2019-01-21 13:07:24.096 DEBUG 10764 --- [  restartedMain] i.g.j.c.apidoc.SwaggerConfiguration      : Started Swagger in 6 ms
```

Somehow swagger can't start and nothing happen.

Edit: The funny thing is that I can run my application with `mvnw` command in cmd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution. I tried to turn on my application in debug mode however when I just run it everything was okay. I removed all breakpoints that I had in code and that helped me.